# How to add a model using add_api_route in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to create a base router class that deals with any type of database entity so that it can add, update and delete among other basic functionality. As I made the class I couldn't figure out how to include the `@router.get("/something")` within the class's methods, so I opted for the alternative of using the function `add_api_route`. But I have ran into a problem of trying to pass the model that it initialises with.

Here is my code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

from domain.services.base import BaseService

"""
    Base Router is very basic and just create a name and a router.
"""
class BaseRouter():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.router = APIRouter(tags=[self.name])

"""
    Basic Router inherit's BaseRouter, it's added functionality is that it handles getting, updating, and deleting
    with any type of entity.
"""
class BasicRouter(BaseRouter):
    def __init__(self, name, entity, model):    
        super().__init__(name)

        self.service = BaseService(name, entity, model)
        self.entity = entity
        self.model = model

        # register routes
        self.router.add_api_route(f"/{self.name}/Get", self.get, methods=["GET"])        
        self.router.add_api_route(f"/{self.name}/Add", self.add, methods=["POST"], response_model=self.model)
        self.router.add_api_route(f"/{self.name}/Update", self.update, methods=["PUT"])
        self.router.add_api_route(f"/{self.name}/Delete", self.delete, methods=["DELETE"])

    async def get(self, id):
        return self.service.getById(id)

    def add(self):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass
    
    def delete(self):
        pass
```

I want to pass in the declared model into the add router, how do I do this? Or is there any other better way to try and do what I am doing?

Thanks alot!

- I have tried looking into the source code of `add_api_route` to find a parameter for a request model.
- I have tried searching the FastAPI docs for the function.
- I have gone on the Flask and FastAPI discord servers.

Comment: At the minute, override each function seems to work because then I can pass in the model type.